# Error Hosting WCF Service in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework, wcf-hosting

I have developed a WCF service,which uses Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1. When i test the service in Windows 7 works fine, but when i host the same service in Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit, it gives below given error.

The type 'MasterSynchronization.MasterSyncService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

In both the cases IIS version is same.  I have tried installing Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 re-distributable package as well of both 32 & 64 bit version.  But no luck.  Please suggest.

Web.Config file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
   <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   </system.web>
   <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
     <service name="SynchronizationLibrary.SyncService">
       <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SynchronizationLibrary.ISyncContract"></endpoint>
     </service>
    </services>
   <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: that's more of WCF configuration error rather than Sync Fx. have you check your WCF config?

Comment: @JuneT Please find the above edit updated with web config file

Comment: what does your .svc file contain?